# Class template argument deduction for template type which is itself an argument for a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, option-type

Is class template argument deduction supported for template types with default arguments which are used within another template type declaration? The following code does not compile with both Clang/GCC trunk, it fails on the line defining `y`:

```
#include <optional>

template <class T = char>
struct C {};

int main() {
    C x;
    std::optional<C> y;
}
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/SgxY90)

Modifying the code to read `std::optional<C<>> y` fixes the issue, but I am a bit surprised this is needed. Is this a compiler issue, or a known language limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has to verify that what is passed to the template matches the anticipated template parameter. Now consider I were to write this with your example, where you don't see `foo`:

```
foo<C> f;
```

Is it a instance of CTAD, or am I passing the template itself? Since one can already pass templates as arguments to other templates.

```
template< template<typename> class T > struct foo {};
```

Allowing for CTAD in that context would make the use of `C` context dependent. In contrast, a template name has no other use when declaring a variable. There is no ambiguity when writing...

```
C c;
```

... that can mean something *other than* CTAD, so it's allowed here. But context matters when the template name is used as a template argument. C++ has a lot of context dependent constructs already, so adding more is usually a bad idea.

Comment: In your example, we do not see `foo`, but the compiler will have to be able to see it once it compiles `foo<C> f;`. So at that point it should be able to determine whether there is any ambiguity and give an error in case there is?

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel - The point is, that a small change to `foo` can change the semantics of the program in an entirely unexpected way. If I was to refactor and say `foo` takes a type now, the meaning of the declaration will silently change! Avoiding the potential for such silent changes is a backbone of C++'s design.

Comment: We could say that in context of template parameters `C` isn't  a typename, because it's an identifier of template. Even if there is a default parameter for it, typename is `C<>`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie - That's what it is now. Adding CTAD on top of it will make it no longer true.